# I am using composer embeded to test my code, when I add request function to interact other server.ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I was writing composer test.In my origin codes, the logic.js include request.post which interact with other server. I add
var request = require('request') in the beginning to avoid error which is
"error 'request' is not defined".
in this way, I can translate the package into a .bna file, and work well.
But when I try to write some unit test with 'embeded', the error came up with
ReferenceError: require is not defined.
I add the 'require' package in my package.json file.

Answer (score 1):

this is because that `'eslint'` is complaining it doesn't know what to do with request when you run `npm test` etc.
We shoud add the comment like

```
/* global getAssetRegistry getFactory emit request */
```

follow the example:
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/basic-sample-network/lib/sample.js#L15