# Error trying invoke business network. require is not defined

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I followed this [tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html) on macOS and upgraded to v0.0.2 using [these model files](https://github.com/johnwalicki/IoT-AssetTracking-Perishable-Network-Blockchain/tree/master/Blockchain/IoT-Perishable-Network). The POST SetupDemo API (curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{}' 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/SetupDemo') returns

```
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "name": "Error",
    "message": "Error trying invoke business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.\nResponse from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: transaction returned with failure: ReferenceError: require is not defined",
    "stack": "Error: Error trying invoke business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.\nResponse from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: transaction returned with failure: ReferenceError: require is not defined\n    at HLFConnection.invokeChainCode (/Users/jps/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:994:30)\n    at <anonymous>"
  }
}
```

The SetupDemo API did work on IBM Cloud BC before without this error.

```
$ node -v
v8.12.0
```

Comment: you need to check your transaction processor function(s). Either you've tried to include a `requires` (node) directive (to try include a new module, which isn't allowed in the Composer Transaction processor functions) - or you're seeing something similar to this Stack Overflow - where they had a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52377517/i-am-using-composer-embeded-to-test-my-code-when-i-add-request-function-to-inte/52377530#52377530

Comment: The code of the transaction processor functions doesn't contain 'requires' and can be found here: https://github.com/johnwalicki/IoT-AssetTracking-Perishable-Network-Blockchain/blob/master/Blockchain/IoT-Perishable-Network/logic.js. Regarding the other recommendation: I did not run 'npm test' - not sure how that solution relates to my problem.

Comment: The error states that in 1 of the javascript files that is being processed there is a reference to `require` and that reference could be for example a variable or a function. Unfortunately it's not possible to get a filename or line number so it is a case of working out all the files that might have been included and searching for the error yourself in the source files. I have looked at the samples and did not see a reference there so maybe an extra file has somehow been included by mistake ? for example a unit test file